# How to fill shape with multiple recursive insets in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape

Basically I want this:
[image]

But done automatically in Inkscape. I imagine parameters like how much space between insets etc.

Or More complicated shapes like:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try playing with Extensions -> Generate from path -> Interpolate

1. Create the star
2. Create the small pentagon and center it within the star
3. Select them both
4. Use the Interpolate to generate the interlaying paths

You may also convert the star to path and modify it before, like making the inner corners rounded etc. Interpolate works with any path.

Comment: That's a neat suggestion. Sometimes (like with this star) it will work, but in most of the cases with complicated shapes it doesn't. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

I would venture to guess the  [image] Blend tool would be your best bet? If you double click it you will get a pop up like such:

[image]

You have a few different options to adjust for your liking, to include how many steps (stars in your case) you would like to generate.

In order to use it (after you set you parameters in the above image. Create two shapes: In your case. A pentagon inside a star.

[image]

Then click on the Blend tool. Click your first shape (it should select it) then click your second shape. You should see the shape generate according to your settings.

[image]

It's not exactly perfect but might put you on the right track. Also keep in mind, this is a very basic exaple. The Blend tool can be very powerful in other applications as well. One last thing, after you blend the objects/shapes you can still manipulate them and the blend will still be in effect after your adjust a point for example.

[Here](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/blending-objects.html) is Adobe's markup on it.

Comment: You should be using multiple offsets instead offsetting once and blending. Quite suprisingly this produces a different result. But did youb actually notice that the question is for Inkscape?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear on that. Edited to indicate this more clearly.